What are the blessings given by Maa Kamakhya?
We all know in SriVidya Mother blesses us with Bhoga and Moksha. She blesses us with Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha everything. Similarly, Maa Matangi blesses us with knowledge and Maa Bagalamukhi helps us fight our enemies. Similarly, I would like to know what are the blessings given by Maa Kamakhya or what are the fruits Maa Kamakhya gives to her devotees. Please provide a scriptural reference if possible.
